# How to understand IOS trace logs

Tags: ios, stack-trace

How to understand a trace from an IOS application

top to bottom (or) bottom to top

```
0     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x0000000195b77bc8 objc_msgSend + 4
1     Foundation                            0x0000000184edfc84 _NSDescriptionWithStringProxyFunc + 68
2     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000183fa9b50 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 6948
3     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000183fa7ff0 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 244
4     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000183fc59dc _CFLogvEx2 + 148
5     Foundation                            0x0000000184dff660 NSLogv + 104
6     Foundation                            0x0000000184dff5e8 NSLog + 20
7     My Mobile                             0x00000001005819b0 -[MySDK didFailWithError:] + 272
8     My Mobile                             0x00000001005d3974 -[MyServiceManager validate:didFailWithError:] + 1200
9     My Mobile                             0x00000001005bb20c __60-[MyHttpCliebt validate]_block_invoke110 + 528
10   MyTIM Mobile                           0x00000001005c2ca8 __84-[AFHTTPSessionManager dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:URLString:parameters:success:failure:]_block_invoke87 + 160
11   My Mobile                              0x00000001005a7ef0 __72-[AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke + 220
12   libdispatch.dylib                      0x00000001961e1994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
13   libdispatch.dylib                      0x00000001961e1954 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
14   libdispatch.dylib                      0x00000001961e620c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1604
15   CoreFoundation                         0x0000000183f97544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
16   CoreFoundation                         0x0000000183f955ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1488
17   CoreFoundation                         0x0000000183ec0f74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
18   GraphicsServices                       0x000000018d7f36fc GSEventRunModal + 164
19   UIKit                                  0x0000000188ac2d94 UIApplicationMain + 1484
20   MyTIM Mobile                           0x00000001000de4a0 main (main.m:12)
21   libdyld.dylib                          0x000000019620ea08 start + 0
```

Please help me in identifying where the problem actually starts, is it starts at  AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate (or) MySDK ?

Which is causing the issue, is **NSLog** causing issue ? or **blocks** and threads causing this issue?

Answer (score -1):

How to analyze a crash report is described in [Technical Note TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html).